# How to execute subquery in Oracle? My query gets parentheses erro

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to execute a query inside LabVIEW so I can informations stored in a Oracle Database, but when a try to execute a query with parenthesis it doesn't works and gives me this erro:

> ADO Error: 0x80004005 Exception occured in Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00907: parêntese direito não encontrado

Here is the SQL query I'm trying to execute:

```
SELECT
F.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO,
F.CODIGOMODELO,
F.INICIOESCALA,
F.FUNDOESCALA,
F.FAIXA,
F.DESCFAIXA,
F.ORDEM,
P.CODIGOPROCEDIMENTO
FROM FAIXAS F INNER JOIN PROCEDS P ON F.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO=(
    SELECT
    CODIGOFAIXAMODELO
    FROM PROCEDS
    WHERE
    PROCEDS.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO=F.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO
    LIMIT 1
    )
WHERE
F.CODIGOMODELO='%CODIGOMODELO%'
ORDER BY F.ORDEM ASC;
```

The `%CODIGOMODELO%` is replaced with a value by LabVIEW.

When I try the following Query it works:

```
SELECT
F.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO,
F.CODIGOMODELO,
F.INICIOESCALA,
F.FUNDOESCALA,
F.FAIXA,
F.DESCFAIXA,
F.ORDEM,
P.CODIGOPROCEDIMENTO
FROM FAIXAS F INNER JOIN PROCEDS P ON F.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO=P.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO
WHERE
F.CODIGOMODELO='%CODIGOMODELO%'
ORDER BY F.ORDEM ASC;
```

The problem with the second solution is that it returns me many P.CODIGOPROCEDIMENTO, and what I want is to get only one even when there are many.

Comment: You cannot use a sub query to join with main table. It will not work. Your second method is the right way.

Comment: I think your get error because there is a `LIMIT` in your query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it this way. It may be more efficient and more readable to avoid trying to evaluate a subquery inside an expression:

```
SELECT
F.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO,
F.CODIGOMODELO,
F.INICIOESCALA,
F.FUNDOESCALA,
F.FAIXA,
F.DESCFAIXA,
F.ORDEM,
P.CODIGOPROCEDIMENTO
FROM FAIXAS F
INNER JOIN (
                SELECT
                P1.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO,
                MAX(P1.CODIGOPROCEDIMENTO) AS CODIGOPROCEDIMENTO
                FROM PROCEDS P1
                GROUP BY P1.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO
           ) P ON P.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO = F.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO
WHERE F.CODIGOMODELO = '%CODIGOMODELO%'
ORDER BY F.ORDEM ASC;
```

`MAX()` is an [Aggregate Function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) that will return *only* one value for each group - specified in the `GROUP BY` clause. Therefore, using a subquery and joining on `CODIGOFAIXAMODELO` ensures that only one row is filtered against the main query.
The results really depend on the key structures, datatypes and how many rows are available in `PROCEDS`. There are of course other, more complex methods to achieve the same result, such as using [Analytic Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions).

Comment: you cannot put subquery in `on` clause. He used subquery on innerjoin

Answer (score 1):

there is no `LIMIT` function in Oracle

you need to use `ROWNUM = 1` or `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY`

Also as it is stated by @APC, you shouldn't be joining your table on a subquery.

Comment: This is correct about the specific syntax of limiting result sets in Oracle. However it misses the bigger problem, which is that the OP shouldn't be **joining on a subquery**.

Comment: As it is already stated by another author I didn't add that but I am going to edit my post now to include that detail as well

Comment: Didn't know Oracle didn't have the LIMIT function, but with the ROWNUM it doesn't work aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write it this way:

```
SELECT
F.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO,
F.CODIGOMODELO,
F.INICIOESCALA,
F.FUNDOESCALA,
F.FAIXA,
F.DESCFAIXA,
F.ORDEM,
P.CODIGOPROCEDIMENTO
FROM FAIXAS F INNER JOIN PROCEDS P ON F.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO=P.CODIGOFAIXAMODELO and ROWNUM = 1
WHERE
F.CODIGOMODELO='%CODIGOMODELO%'
ORDER BY F.ORDEM ASC;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I want to receive all rows from FAIXAS but with only one value on the P.CODIGOPROCEDIMENTO.

Comment: Hi Can you provide a sample table with data? And expected results. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use `ROWNUM` in join criteria, because it is a [Pseudo Column](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) that is only available for the result set. You would need to nest the `ROWNUM` in a subquery. But if you are going down that path it would be better/more efficient to use [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm#i86310)